# Singapore Mobile Number RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

The phone number should start with `+65`, followed by `6|8|9` with a total of 11 digits. For example: `+6598798765`

Comment: Have you tried to solve this? If yes, [edit] the question and add the regex.

Answer (score 8):

```
/\+65(6|8|9)\d{7}/g
```

`\+` matches the character + literally (case sensitive)

`65` matches the characters 65 literally (case sensitive)

1st Capturing Group (6|8|9)

- 1st Alternative 6 (6 matches the character 6 literally (case sensitive))
- 2nd Alternative 8 (8 matches the character 8 literally (case sensitive))
- 3rd Alternative 9 (9 matches the character 9 literally (case sensitive))

`\d{7}` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

`{7}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 7 times

Comment: Thank You!

It Din't work :(

Comment: The pattern error is a typo, I fixed the `or` selection @Tushar.

Comment: This is Correct \+65[6|8|9]\d{7}

Thanks

Comment: The one in the answer is correct, the one you stated as correct may match a `|` character as @Tushar noted

Comment: Are you sure 6 is the starting letter for Singapore mobile number? I know only 8 or 9 starting digit.

Comment: @Singapore - The answer was based on the numbers provided within the question, you may be right though...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the cap(^) to indicate start of a string and EOS($) to specify the end of string.

```js
var re=/^\+65(6|8|9)\d{7}$/;
var true_mob = "+6561234567";
var false_mob = "+6512345678";
console.log(re.test(true_mob));
console.log(re.test(false_mob));
```