# Singapore mobile number regex with spaces in between

Tags: regex, phone-number

I am trying to make a regular expression that matches Singapore phone numbers. The key part is that the numbers may or may not have spaces in between.

My requirements are:

1. The number should start with `+65`.
2. The next number should be either `6`, `8`, or `9`.
3. The next 7 characters should be any digit from `0` to `9`.

For example: `+6581234567`

I searched through Stack Overflow and found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42478799/singapore-mobile-number-regex) which does the exact same thing above.

Now like I said above, there could be spaces in between. And I'm not sure how to do the spaces. So the possible combinations are these two.

1. `+6581234567`
2. `+65 8123 4567`

Comment: Can spaces be anywhere or just the 2 in your example?

Comment: Also, are `+65 81234567` and `+658123 4567` acceptable?

Comment: No @PoulBak. The only number combinations that are allowed are the ones I posted above.

Comment: This question is perfectly clear and should not have been closed as "needs details or clarity".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^\+65(\s?)[689]\d{3}\1\d{4}$
```

This will allow any whitespace symbol after `+65` and before last 4 digits.

- `^` and `$` start and end of the string,
- `\+65` matches literal "+65",
- `(\s?)` matches an optional whitespace character. Caprured into group #1, and matched content will later be back referenced as `\1`,
- `[689]` matches any one of digits: 6, 8, or 9,
- `\d{3}` and `\d{4}` matches three and four digits accordingly,
- `\1` matches the same content that was in group #1.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/r2OwtC/2).

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression may be answer for this:

```
^(?:\+65\s?)?8[0-9]{7}$
```

You can use the following webpage to match the patterns: https://pythex.org/

Comment: This doesn't allow for `+65 8123 4567`, and only allows 8 as regional code.

Comment: Correct, doesn't work for my use case.